# Get values based on Selected value from drop down in Scala Template

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

This is the map i want to iterate on drop down

```
[permissions : Map[Role, List[Permission]]

<select name="role" class="form-control">
    @for((key, value) <- permissions) {
        <option value="@key.role">@key.display</option>
    }   
</select>
```

Now i want to display the Permission object properties based on the selected value from the dropdown. Is there any way to achieve it? I can make a ajax call at onchange event. But i don't want to do, since already i have the Permission properties here.

Comment: Just concept: you can build JavaScript object in the view using your `permissions` Map and then just use `onchange` to  call the function which will use its data without additional AJAX request.